# Why does my titlepage not show up?

Tags: formatting, titles

This is my whole document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\title{Refenssystemet IEEE}
\author{MTAC20h}
\date{October 2020}
\end{titlepage}


\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{1} R. Grahn och P. Jansson, \textit{Mekanik : statik och dynamik}, upplaga 3., 
Polen: Studentlitteratur AB, 2013. [Online]. Tillgänglig: 
\url{https://www.smakprov.se/smakprov/?isbn=9789144085784&l=bokus}, 
Hämtad: Okt 04, 2020.

\bibitem{2} M. van Biezen, Professor, ``Mechanical Engineering: Centroids and Center of Gravity (6 of 35) Center of Gravity of a Semi Circle,''
\textit{Youtube}, 2015. [Video]. Tillgänglig: 
\url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkm8TbUt5H4}, 
hämtad: 2020-10-04.

\bibitem{3} Studentliterattur, ``Mekanik: statik och dynamik: a) Masscentrum, statisk moment,`` 2013. [Elektronisk bild]. Tillgänglig: \url{https://www.smakprov.se/smakprov/?isbn=9789144085784&l=bokus}. Hämtad: 2020-10-06.

\bibitem{4} TED-Ed, Producent, ``An athlete uses physics to shatter world records - Asaf Bar-Yosef,`` \textit{Youtube}, 2014. [Video]. Tillgänglig: \url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaGUW1d0w8g}, hämtad: 2020-10-02.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I have tried with codes like \newpage and \cleardoublepage to see if it would help but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the command `\maketitle` at the end of your `title` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} % <== this should be the last package to be loaded!

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\title{Refenssystemet IEEE}
\author{MTAC20h}
\date{October 2020}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: omgosh i forgot that thank you.